# Passing struct from middleware to route in GinGonic

Tags: go, go-gin

I'm making a custom middleware that checks if the user is currently logged in, is there any way I can pass CurrentUser struct into the route in a way I can access the variable in the code **and** template?

```
func LoginMiddleware(database *sqlx.DB) gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        var (
            err    error
            cookie string
            user   CurrentUser
        )

        // Get the cookie from the request
        cookie, err = c.Cookie("cookie")
        if err != nil {
            // If the cookie does not exist, set the current user to nil
            c.Set("currentUser", nil)
            c.Next()
            return
        }

        // Check if the cookie exists in the database
        err = database.Get(&user, "SELECT user_id, username, email FROM users WHERE user_id = (SELECT user_id FROM sessions WHERE cookie = ?)", cookie)
        if err != nil {
            // If the cookie does not exist, set the current user to nil
            c.Set("currentUser", nil)
            c.Next()
            return
        }

        // If the cookie exists, set the current user to the user
        user.Cookie = cookie
        c.Set("currentUser", user)

        // Continue with the request
        c.Next()
    }
}
```

This is my current way of doing this, I can successfully do a `c.get("currentUser")` when I pass it directly into the template, but not when I want to use the value in code, I tried `blah := c.MustGet("currentUser").(CurrentUser)` and the following code

```
func HandleProfileGet(c *gin.Context) {
    var (
        currentUser  CurrentUser
        userSessions []SessionRow
        err          error
    )

    getCurrentUser, _ := c.Get("currentUser")
    currentUser, ok := getCurrentUser.(CurrentUser)
    if !ok {
        c.String(500, "Internal server error")
        return
    }

    err = Database.Select(&userSessions, "SELECT session_id, user_id, cookie FROM sessions WHERE user_id = ?", currentUser.UserId)
    if err != nil {
        c.String(500, "Internal server error")
        return
    }

    c.HTML(200, "profile", gin.H{
        "CurrentUser":  currentUser,
        "UserSessions": userSessions,
    })
}
```

both of which panic. I'm still new to go and gin so please be patient!

Comment: Have you confirmed that `LoginMiddleware` successfully proceeds to the last `c.Next`? Because the other `c.Next()` calls that set the currentUser to `nil` will obviously cause a panic in any handler in the chain if it doesn't guard against `nil`.

Comment: @mkopriva yes, it successfully proceeds to the last `c.Next`, even when the value is nil. This route is also in a group that can only be accessed when `c.Get("currentUser")` isnt `nil`

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was mixing types!

I had 2 different `CurrentUser` structs in 2 files, as I'm new to Go I thought that would be fine as long as they had the same values, turns out no. I fixed the type miss-match by making this function in the file that holds my middleware

```
func GetCurrentUser(currentUser *CurrentUser, c *gin.Context) error {
    if c.MustGet("currentUser") == nil {
        return errors.New("current user is nil")
    }

    *currentUser = c.MustGet("currentUser").(CurrentUser)

    return nil
}
```

and editing my profile route to this

```
func HandleProfileGet(c *gin.Context) {
    var (
        userSessions []SessionRow
        currentUser  middleware.CurrentUser
        err          error
    )

    _ = middleware.GetCurrentUser(&currentUser, c)

    err = Database.Select(&userSessions, "SELECT session_id, user_id, cookie FROM sessions WHERE user_id = ?", currentUser.UserId)
    if err != nil {
        c.String(500, "Internal server error")
        return
    }

    c.HTML(200, "profile", gin.H{
        "CurrentUser":  c.MustGet("currentUser"),
        "UserSessions": userSessions,
    })
}
```